# Yii2 .htaccess rules not working on production env

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii2-advanced-app

I've a yii2 site with advanced template, in my local apache all run perfectly, now I've put on production server the site and init it in production enviroment. For server policy the only way to configure two distinct link for frontend and backend is to use symbolic link, the division between frontend and backend work fine but now the problem is configure the .htaccess file for the rewrite rules,this is the local configuration for frontend:

```
'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [ .... ]
```

My .htaccess rules in frontend/web/ :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /home/path/to/my-site/

RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

With this configuration tha page load the layout but return the 404 error, how i can configure the application for work correctly?

Comment: Does the same happen when you remove `RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]` line?

Comment: Yes, the same error... 404!

Answer (score 0):

A partial soplution is to change RewriteBase to:

```
RewriteBase /
```

with this rule i can access at all pages but the home page still does not work and return 404 error.